# Variables in Vb.net

Tags: vb.net

Here is what im trying to do. I have a loop and trying to concatenate it to produce the string. For whatever reason im getting test1, test2, etc instead of the variable equals to.
What i am trying to do is get the value test1, etc.... from the concatenating test & cstr(a)

```
dim test1, test2, test3, test4, test 5 as string
test1 = "The"
test2 = "dog"
test3 = "came"
test4 = "to"
test5 = "play"

for a = 1 to 5
  label1.text += test & cstr(a) & " " 
next
```

Comment: what is the `test` variable defined in this line `label1.text += test & cstr(a) & " " `

Comment: Please post code that will at least _compile_. The keywords are not property capitalized and one of your declared variables has a _space_.

Comment: Op is trying to build variables names on the fly to get their values... if you want something like this you better use an array or any other structure. this: label1.text += test & cstr(a) & " "  will just write what you post, it will not get the value inside the variable... And to Oded, this is VB, so no need to capitalize anything.

Comment: You can't put those strings in an array or list?

Comment: @gbianchi - Apart from capitalization, the code on the first line is OK? The "test 5" variable is fine?

Comment: no, that is not ok.. obviously not! but anybody can make a copy mistake.. ;) give him the benefit of doubt...

Answer (score 5):

I don't think you can dynamically create the variable names like you're trying to do with your `test & cstr(a)` piece of code. However, try something like this instead if it's an option for you:

```
    Dim test1, test2, test3, test4, test5 As String
    test1 = "The"
    test2 = "dog"
    test3 = "came"
    test4 = "to"
    test5 = "play"

    Dim testArray As String() = New String() {test1, test2, test3, test4, test5}

    For a As Integer = 0 To testArray.Length - 1
        label1.Text += testArray(a) & " "
    Next
```

Answer (score 0):

To the best of my knowledge, there's no way in VB to generate a variable name dynamically and expect VB to be able to access it. You could accomplish something resembling what you want by creating an array and looping through the elements of the array.